# How to match stream response of type text/plain with PACT GO?

Tags: go, pact

I am trying to use the PACT framework in GO and I want to match a stream response of type text/plain which looks similar to:

```
{"Id": 1224, "Name": "Ana", "Age": 5}
{"Id": 34, "Name": "Lele", "Age": 4}
```

I know it can be done with regex but I am interested in actually checking if each row is of a certain object type, similar to EackLike("Person") which works if response is json - array of objects.

Do you have any suggestion? Or how a custom Matcher would look like?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported in HTTP Pact. You would need to use Message Pact and make each one an individual message.